# Bound mismatch how to match them?

Tags: java, bounds

So I'm getting the following error

> Bound mismatch: The type Block is not a valid substitute for the
> bounded parameter <T extends Comparable> of the type List

This is the line of code I wrote in main

```
List<Block>customerData = new List<Block>();
```

Classes involved

```
public class List<T extends Comparable<T>>{
public interface Transaction {
public class Block implements Transaction{
```

I understand there is an error because List extends comparable and Block implements transaction. How can I edit anyone of the transaction so the bounds match?

Fixed with `comparable<block>`

Comment: How about making `Block` also implement `Comparable<Block>`?

Comment: List doesn't extend Comparable. It requires a type parameter of a class which extends Comparable, which Block does not. If you look at the List implementation it presumably calls a method from the Comparable interface on the items you store in it. So you will need to make Block implement Comparable.